# Overlaying objects with CSS fails miserably in IE

Tags: css, firefox, internet-explorer-8

What I'm going for is a button with a outlined description box positioned down and to the right, but still partly behind the button.  Open up FF 4 and see how it is supposed to look:

http://jsfiddle.net/kZFRN/16/

In IE (8), the button is positioned to the right of the description box, which kind of defeats the beauty of the thing.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Niklas' solution below works for a single instance of the layered DIV.  Is there a method to have two pairs of the layered divs on the same page, without resorting to hard coding absolutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change position on yellowbox

```
.yellowbox{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: If this helped you then you should mark this as an answer, or post your own answer and mark that =)

Comment: It more or less worked.. with a single div.  Having two buttons on the same page created a problem.  It's been a while since I worked on this.. I'll try to dig up the code for two buttons.